# Where does gtag pageview's 'page_location' get reported?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm using the Google Analytics's **gtag.js** on a single-page webapp (SPA).  As [suggested in the docs for SPAs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/single-page-applications), I've disabled the automatic `send_page_view` and instead explicitly send a page view by setting a `page_path` and `page_title` to the gtag config. So far, so good.

The docs [also list an optional `page_location` parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages) to send the page's full URL.  For my app's search page, I'm particularly interested in getting the full query params after the `?` in the URL, so I tried adding it to that payload:

```
   gtag('config', GA_TRACKING_ID, {
     page_location: window.location.href,
     page_title: 'app search page',
     page_path: '/search',
   });
```

However  I never see a full URL in either the Anlaytics web UI or in its export to BigQuery.  I only the `page_title` and `page_path`.  Where does `page_location` end up getting stored or reported?

Comment: you may also be able to find help here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll ask future questions to webmasters.SE.  If you work at Google, heads up that their pages point users to Stack Overflow, not webmasters.SE: https://developers.google.com/analytics/community#developer-discussion-groups

Comment: I know it does i have asked them to fix that a number of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page_location` is not reported in Analytics but might be used for processing source and medium parameters and for extracting `page_path` if not provided.

Comment: So you're suggesting that if I had set `page_location` but not `page_path`, then it would use this to derive the missing `page_path`?